# Modify/manipulate data in-flight during import from CSV

Tags: sql-server, csv, import, database-design

We need to import data from a CSV into a MS-SQL table.  It looks something like this:

```
ticket,time_spent,created,closed
1337,123:45:67,1/2/2022 10:00:00,2/1/2022 10:00:00
```

The second column is the problem.  It's time spent on a ticket in the format of HH:MM:SS.  There isn't a corresponding datatype in SQL.  My thought was using an INT and storing the time in seconds.  So, the table would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tickets (
 Ticket int NOT NULL,
 time_spent int,
 created datetime(1),
 closed datetime(1)
 )
```

Normally, the import would be very simple, like below...  Where I'm left scratching my head is how to convert that second column "time_spent" into an INT during the import process.

```
BULK INSERT tickets
FROM 'c:\temp\tickets.csv'
WITH (
 FIRSTROW = 2,
 FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
 ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
 TABLOCK
)
```

Anyone know a way to convert hours:minutes:seconds into simply seconds stored in an Int, during the import process?

Comment: Assuming you don't have any values greater than 23 hours you might be able to bring that into a time datatype. Then you could add another column and do some basic date math to convert it to seconds.

Comment: Unfortunately there are values beyond 24-hours.  The datetime datatypes are also not a great choice, as they implicitly have dates.

Comment: If they are beyond 24 hours you will probably have to import to a character datatype and then convert afterwards.

Comment: I'm assuming you can't use processing tools like Perl or anything to simplify the data first? Hideous way that MIGHT work: make the delimiter either comma or colon, and then clean up the resulting database (which will have many more columns than you need)

Comment: I've considered using Powershell or Excel to manipulate the data before import, or importing it as a varchar and manipulating it in any query that accesses it... but was hoping there was a more graceful "have your cake and eat it too" approach that I was missing.

Comment: If you're married to `bulk insert` to read the CSV file then you'll need to bulk insert into a temporary/staging table first - where the `time_spent` column is character based - then transform it to another data type while inserting it into your final destination table in a second statement. If you need it in one shot then consider [openrowset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql) with an [outer apply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql).

Answer (score 0):

The best answered seemed to be a bit of powershell.

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path import.csv
foreach($i in $csv){
    [int]$h, [int]$m, [int]$s = $i.time_spent.Split(":")
    $t = ($h * 3600) + ($m * 60) + $s
    if($t -gt 0){$i.time_spent = $t}else{$i.time_spent = $null}
}
$csv | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | % {$_.Replace('"','')} | Out-File export.csv
```

Appreciate everyone's advice!